# NSIS Setting temporary Environment Variables does not work

Tags: environment-variables, nsis

I'm trying to update the path of my JAVA_HOME Following the instruction of [this page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Setting_Environment_Variables) 
But just after having set new value, the value seems not to have changed.

This is my code :

```
StrCpy $TemplateJavaPath "$INSTDIR\jdk1.7.0_03"
System::Call 'Kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariableA(t, t) i("JAVA_HOME", "$TempJavaPath").r0'
ReadEnvStr $R0 "JAVA_HOME" 
MessageBox MB_OK $R0 ; The value is still C:\program Files\Java6...
ExecWait '"C:\test.bat" ;containing the single line echo %JAVA_HOME%, set to Java6...
```

I made the same test with PATH with the same result.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The wiki page where you got that code is/was wrong, you should never mix the A/W function suffix with the `t` type.

```
Var /Global TempJavaPath
StrCpy $TempJavaPath "C:\foo\bar"
System::Call 'kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "JAVA_HOME", t "$TempJavaPath")i'
Exec '"cmd" /k echo %JAVA_HOME%'
```

This will only work for processes started by your setup, you need to write to the registry if this variable should apply to all processes...

Comment: Hi Anders. Thanks for your answer. I think you already post this answer on another subject talking about it no ? Unfortunately I already tried the code you wrote, with the same result.